# Prevent emails from being deleted in one specific child folder of the Outlook inbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-redemption

I'm attempting to figure out how to restrict one folder in Outlook 2010 from having it's mailitems deleted. I have the following code example that works well but only works on the inbox folder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox). I'm trying to figure out how to restrict one folder and one folder only below the inbox. For example Inbox\ReadMail where I want to prevent users from deleting from ReadMail only. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

```
 public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
    Outlook.Inspectors inspectors = null;
    Outlook.Folder fldr = null;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;

        // Is there a way to edit the folloing line to point to a certain sub folder of the inbox folder?
        inspectors.NewInspector += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler (Inspectors_NewInspector);

        fldr = (Outlook.Folder)this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        fldr.BeforeItemMove += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler(fldr_BeforeItemMove);

    }

    void fldr_BeforeItemMove(object Item, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder MoveTo, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are not permitted to delete emails from this folder");
        Cancel = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line

```
fldr = (Outlook.Folder)this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

with

```
fldr = (Outlook.Folder)this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Folders["ReadMail"];
```

Comment: I was missing the .Folders...Also I asked the wrong question. I needed to prevent deletions from the store level down and not at the inbox folder level down so I ended up with this - fldr = (Outlook.Folder)this.Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder().Folders["ReadMail"];  But you sent me down the right path, so to speak : )

Comment: If you are running in Outlook 2003 or older, stores are not exposed, but you can still make your code work by opening the parent of the Inbox folder: Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders["ReadMail"];

Comment: One last question. Is there a way to deal with child folders of ReadMail? I'm trying to restrict subfolders also. I was not sure if there was some sort of wildcard that I could use. I imagine I need to build a collection of folders if there's no wildcard to include subfolders but I even tried to modify the original line to include just one subfolder as a test . Example fldr = (Outlook.Folder)this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Folders["ReadMail\1"];  to include a subfolder "1" but I can't nail down the syntax

Comment: Yes, you will need to store the folder references in a list and set up an event handler separately on each folder.